# Dolphin not opening konsole view when F4 is pressed

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma, file-manager, konsole

When F4 is pressed in Dolphin, it used to open a konsole view (at the bottom of Dolphin). But it is not working in 21.10 and 22.04 (beta)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-install `kinit` as mentioned [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/konsole-not-working-in-dolphin/78822)

Full command: `sudo apt install kinit --reinstall`